# I want to use BackgroundWorker to speed up my graphical appearances

Tags: c#, winforms, backgroundworker, picturebox

I am writing a Kiosk-type program for a media center PC.  I have some pictureBoxes as my buttons, and would like a label or another pictureBox (acting as a label) to be visible/not visible and be triggered by a MouseEnter and MouseLeave event.

When the MouseLeave event happens(triggering Visible=false), a white box appears in place of the pictureBox or label that was previously there for a split second until the background image fills back in.

I have read up a little bit on using the BackgroundWorker to "pre-load" my pictureBox or labels.  I am not sure that i am doing it right.  I am very new to programming; i dabble here and there, and do not have any formal training in c#.

I am not looking for anyone to write the code for me, but i also am not objected to that either.  A simple example of how to use it should suffice.

I have a background image (1920x1080) on my form. I think this image is actually having a harder time refreshing after the label or pictureBox's visibility is set to false.

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                     this.pictureBox9.Visible = true;
        }
private void pictureBox1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.pictureBox9.Visible = false;
        }
```

I am attempting to use the backgroundWorker DoWork event, but really have no idea what i am doing.

```
    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
            this.pictureBox9.Visible = true;
            this.pictureBox9.Visible = false;
    }
```

My question is, "How do i use backgroundworker to effectively reduce the lag caused by changing visibilty of my pictureBoxes or lables?

Comment: A thread will work well to preload data, so it will do it without jamming up your UI .. such as, you want to scan your HD for a file name, if you run that just in code on a button click, your form will freeze until it finishes, put the search code in a thread the UI remains responsive, but you have to deal with handing data between the two. Using a thread to change elements of the UI directly is not normally that good an idea.   have you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741666/slow-screen-drawing-in-net-c-sharp-winforms-application ?

Comment: Hi Adam, it seems that you've got more than one account. If this is accidental, and you want to merge your accounts, please follow the steps listed here; http://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts

Answer (score 2):

The BackgroundWorker works like this:

```
    BackgroundWorker workerOne = new BackgroundWorker();
    BackgroundWorker workerTwo = new BackgroundWorker();
    private void MyForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        workerOne.DoWork += workerOne_DoWork;
        workerTwo.DoWork += workerTwo_DoWork;
    }
    private void ThingOne_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        workerOne.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
    private void ThingOne_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        workerTwo.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
    void workerOne_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        //This will run as async and not interupt main thread
    }
    void workerTwo_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        //This will run as async and not interupt main thread
    }
```

I've included two in the example.  Basically the RunWorkerAsync breaks it off in its own thread.

Answer (score 1):

I do not recommend using BackgroundWorker for this because the fact of changing the Visibility of a Visual Element requires the Main Thread and not a Worker Thread. What I recommend in any case is to handle the Opacity so you don't have to load the image again.